# How to get rid of extra space in handlebars.js when value is undefined (w/o using #if)?

Tags: javascript, handlebars.js

I have some content like this:

```
<div>{{someText}} {{someText2}} more text</div>
```

I've noticed when someText2 is undefined, there is an extra space between `{{someText}}` and "more text".

I know one solution is I could use an `{{#if}}` to say:

```
{{#if someText2}} 
     <div>{{someText}} {{someText2}} more text</div> 
{{else}}
     <div>{{someText}} more text</div>  
{{/if}}
```

problem is, this file is provided to another handlebars file, all this content is being injected into `{{{text}}}`. I tried the above approach and it doesn't work. I haven't tried using `{{#unless}}` or other condition keywords, but I'd assume if this doesn't work then that approach won't either.

If anyone has another approach I could try I'd really appreciate it. Thank you for reading

Answer (score 1):

This is because you have 2 spaces 1 before someText2 and 1 after.
You could solve this by appending a space in your if block:

```
<div>{{someText}} {{#if someText2}}{{someText2}} {{/if}}more text</div>
```

Note that there is no space before "more text" and a space after {{someText2}}, so only if someText2 is defined there will be a space.

Comment: Thanks, this makes sense. I tried this and unfortunately it doesn't work since all of this, is going into {{{text}}} so it's not getting evaluated and I end up getting <div>"{{someText}} {{#if someText2}}{{someText2}} {{/if}}more text"</div>. Not sure how to get around the second issue. But this does solve the question in the title of my post so I've upvoted.

Comment: @JonathanLee You have to compile it of course (using Handlebars), check there website. If you want to inject it into antoher template you can just compile this and put the result into the other template. https://handlebarsjs.com/api-reference/compilation.html#handlebars-compile-template-options